# Get a list of filtered values for a single field from a Django model

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get a list of the values for one of the fields in a Django model.

I can do the following:

```
MyObject.objects.filter(name='Mike').values_list('address')
```

But this gives me a list of tuples with a single element each, which I then need to convert to a list.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do what you are looking for:

```
MyObject.objects.filter(name='Mike').values_list('address', flat=True)
```

What you were missing was the [flat](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) keyword.